# How do I make the featured images to display when image size 960*250 in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I am customizing a WordPress theme and facing some problems with the featured image.

If there is a featured image on post or page - AND - that featured image is 960x250 THEN the featured image appears as the header on that post or page.

If the featured image IS NOT 960x250 Then that featured image should be displayed in the main content area, filling the space horizontally ( just like it does now in posts)
If, and only if, featured image is 960x250, it ONLY appears as header, NOT in content

Comment: i am use this code       <?php if( has_post_thumbnail(array(960,250))) {
                        the_post_thumbnail(); } ?>

Comment: Shubham, you are free to [edit] your Question whenever needed. This info belongs in the Q.

Comment: are you trying to make the featured image appear in the header at 960x250 and appear in content at any other size? just making sure because your questions content seemed like a statement more than a question..

Comment: my Question is "If the featured image IS NOT 960x250 Then that featured image should not be display." how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way of writing that would be

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
  $headerImg = get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, array(960,250) );
}
```

`has_post_thumbnail()` only accepts optionally the id

**EDITED**

```
$headerImg = wp_get_attachment_image_src($post->ID, array(960,250));

if (has_post_thumbnail() && $headerImg[1] == 960 && $headerImg[2] == 250) {
 // if it is output is 960x250 in size
 $headerImg = the_post_thumbnail(array(960,250));
} else {
 // if it isn't then show the medium or some other size image
 $contentImg = the_post_thumbnail('medium');
}
```

**FURTHER EDITED**

```
$headerImg = get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, array(960,250) );
if (has_post_thumbnail() && !empty($headerImg) ){
 #This checks to see if the post has the thumbnail and the image is 960x250.
 #Therefore you can now add it to the header.
 $headerImg = get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, array(960,250) );
} elseif (has_post_thumbnail() && empty($headerImg) {
   #This checks to see if thumbnail exists and works if 960x250 is empty
} else {
 #Place code here if the featured image doesnt exist
}
```

Comment: if the featured image is small then featured image should not be displayed some think like this code `code` if ( has_post_thumbnail(array(960,250) ) ) {
  $headerImg = get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, array(960,250) );
}

Comment: again `has_post_thumbnail` accepts only an $id param please read [**here**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_post_thumbnail)

Comment: ok. is it possible that if we are set thumbnail image is smaller(particular image size 960*250) then thumbnail image should not be display in page or post. ? how

Comment: i hope r u understand my problem ,and above edited code doesn't work always call else condition.

Comment: so now your checking if has_post_thumbnail and if thats true along with width = 960 and height = 250 then header image variable equals the image otherwise give it to the content

Comment: [link](http://awesomescreenshot.com/0ac10nj5a7) and [link](http://awesomescreenshot.com/0e110njlf4) always else condition call .i am use this code  `<?php 
$headerImg = wp_get_attachment_image_src($post->ID, array(960,250));

if (has_post_thumbnail() && $headerImg[1] == 960 && $headerImg[2] == 250) {
 // if it is output is 960x250 in size
 $headerImg = the_post_thumbnail(array(960,250));
echo 'done';
} else {
 // if it isn't then show the medium or some other size image
 $contentImg = the_post_thumbnail('medium');
echo 'fail;';
} ?>`